# Is coalescing triggered for accessing memory in reverse order?

Tags: memory, cuda, coalesce

Let's say I have several threads and they access memory at addresses A+0, A+4, A+8, A+12 (each access = next thread). Such access is coalesced, right?

However if I have access the same memory but in reverse order, meaning:

```
thread 0 -> A+12
thread 1 -> A+8
thread 2 -> A+4
thread 3 -> A+0
```

Is coalescing here also triggered?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, for cc 2.0 and newer GPUs, coalescing will occur for any random arrangement of 32 bit data elements to threads, as long as all the requested 32-bit data elements are coming from (requested from) the same 128 byte (and 128 byte aligned) region in global memory.

The GPU has something like a "crossbar switch" in the memory controller that will distribute elements as needed.  You may be interested in [this GPU webinar](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/CUDA/training/bandwidthlimitedkernels_webinar.pdf) which discusses coalescing and will illustrate this particular case pictorially (on slide 12).

The [NVIDIA webinar page](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpu-computing-webinars) has other useful webinars you may be interested in as well.

For pre-cc2.0 devices  [the specifics vary by compute capability](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#global-memory-1-x), but compute 1.0 and 1.1 capable devices do not have this ability to coalesce reads that are in "reverse order" or random order.

Comment: Thank you very much. For the record there is also video from this webinar: http://developer.download.nvidia.com/CUDA/training/Optimizing_Mem_limited_kernels.mp4

Answer (score 2):

It's also worth noting that a main purpose of the L2 cache in an Nvidia GPU is to collapse reads and coalesce writes. So if one warp was accessing

```
thread 0 -> A+0
thread 1 -> A+8
thread 2 -> A+16
thread 3 -> A+24
...
```

and another warp was accessing

```
thread 0 -> A+4
thread 1 -> A+12
thread 2 -> A+20
thread 3 -> A+28
...
```

these two accesses will not coalesce inside the SM but generally will coalesce in the L2 cache, so that GPU memory will only be touched once.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this? I see this working for reads, but for writes, will the GPU try to align up transactions that appear in different warps and different SMs so that they occur at the exact same time, so that they can be combined by L2? Or will L2 "hold" the data for a while to see if there are more updates to it, before writing it out to global memory?

Comment: @RogerDahl The L2 is a "write-back" cache ([refer to slide 15](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/CUDA/training/cuda_webinars_GlobalMemory.pdf)).  It will collapse (generally, subject to eviction, thrashing, etc.) reads and coalesce (again, generally) writes.  You may want to read up on the [write behavior of a write-back cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)#Writing_policies).