# Streaming global memory: Performance loss when accessing in reversed order?

Tags: opencl, gpgpu

When processing elements of a global array (writing or reading), one entry in one work item, it's known to be more efficient if I access adjacent memory addresses for adjacent work items. This is because the memory is "streamed".

Is there any performance issue when the order of such accesses is in reverse order, i.e. if work item `X` accesses an address similar to `size - 1 - X`?

Also, should only the first dimension be considered when thinking about performance?

---

I'm currently doing a homework assessment for a GPGPU course in which we should rotate a matrix. We should do this block-wise in work groups to achieve best performance. The idea is to first copy the source block into local memory, rotate it locally and write it then back at the correct position. I first implemented a transposition (mirroring at the diagonal) and now want to mirror it. I could now simply access the result array for the matrix with mirrored indices if this is not a performance issue (maximum performace is a requirement for this homework task).

Comment: For CUDA memory coalesced access is triggered in such a case, but not for all devices, olders one don't. Post some code, maybe the problem is elsewhere. Is your main memory aligned properly?

Comment: Found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15029765/is-coalescing-triggered-for-accessing-memory-in-reverse-order